# Esfregar o móvel ou limpar o móvel?

Tags: significado, verbos, diferenças

> Eu estou na sala de estar, esfregando o móvel.
>
> Eu estou na sala de estar, limpando o móvel.

I am in the livingroom, wiping down furniture.

I am confused about using *limpar* and *esfregar*. They both mean ***to wipe down***. Are there any alternative for it?

Comment: Short answer: limpar = to clean / esfregar = to rub.

Comment: esfregar algo em termos de limpeza: to scrub, not rub. esfregar o chão: to scrub the floor.

Answer (score 7):

*Limpar* means *to clean*, not specifically *to wipe down*.

The main meaning of *esfregar* is *to rub*, though, indeed, it can also mean *to mop*, *to scrub* or *to wipe* (a surface). A mop is called *esfregona*, from *esfregar* + the suffix *ona*, and you could translate *mop the floor* as *esfregar o chão*.

However, as applied to furniture, it doesn't sound very idiomatic, maybe because it seems too agressive an action for something relatively fragile such as furniture (as compared to the floor, or a big pot). You would more likely say *limpar o móvel* or *limpar o pó ao móvel*, if you're specifically removing dust.

Comment: limpar o pó no móvel não é idiomático. wipe down em inglês quer dizer; to wipe down ***with a cloth***

Comment: @Lambie Eu escrevi _limpar o pó **ao** móvel_. Não é exatamente o mesmo que _wipe down **with a cloth**_ (podemos limpar o pó com um espanador, por exemplo), mas, de qualquer forma, _wipe down_ não é necessariamente com um pano também (embora de facto geralmente seja).

Comment: Sim, to wipe down (furniture) with a cloth or sponge, not a feather duster. . Any native speaker will tell you that.  E é por isso que é preciso dizer em português: passar un pano no móvel. Nenhuma pessoa que limpa movéis diria: limpar o pó ao móvel.  Soa muito estranho. Se tira pó do móvel, se desempoera o móvel.

Comment: @Lambie Estás a insinuar que eu não limpo móveis?

Comment: Não, Estou dizendo que /limpar pó ao móvel/ não faz parte do génio do português. Se se limpa pó, o pó estaria sujo. Se limpa casa, se limpa um móvel, se limpa objetos. E eu agora vou me mandar. :)

Comment: @Lambie Mais a sério, **tu** talvez não digas _limpar o pó a (qualquer coisa)_, mas eu digo e a internet está cheia de exemplos. Por exemplo, [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22limpar+o+p%C3%B3+ao%22) com _ao_ (_a_ + _o_).

Comment: @Lambie Quiçá diferença transatlântica. De qualquer forma, por cá também se diz _passar um pano em (qualquer coisa)_, e eu concordo que esteja mais perto de _wipe down_.

Comment: *Limpar o pó* também se encontra no Brasil, mas parece-me que o mais comum é *espanar*.

Comment: Não, o mais comun é tirar o pó ou desempoera. Mas wipe down implica a cloth em inglés.  A feather duster is not used to wipe down furniture. It is used to dust furniture. Limpar o pó =to dust; wipe down=passar um pano [para tirar o pó]; come que sei? Já morei nos dois. E conheço muitas mulheres (umas cinco) que limpam casas nos EUA.

Comment: @Lambie Eu nunca afirmo que _wipe down_ pode envolver um espanador. Quando disse que _wipe down_ não é necessariamente com um pano não queria dizer que podia ser com um espanador, referia-me mais a toalhas, esponjas, etc.; coisas que se fazem deslizar pela superfície. Quando a _limpar o pó_, é verdade que _to dust_ é uma tradução adequada, mas reapara que _to dust_, **tal como limpar o pó**, contempla a possibilidade de essa limpeza ser feita com um pano (o Oxford Dictionaries, p.ex. fala em _remove the dust or dirt from the surface of (something) by **wiping** or brushing it_).

Comment: No Brasil, as expressões mais comuns certamente são "limpar o móvel", "passar um pano no móvel" e "tirar o pó do móvel". "espanar o móvel" e "limpar o pó do móvel" são outras opções, mas creio que são menos utilizadas. Note a diferença de preposição em relação ao português de Portugal. "Desempoeirar o móvel" realmente existe, mas eu nunca escutei na língua falada. Dentre todas essas opções, a mais próxima de "to wipe down furniture" é "passar um pano nos móveis (mais usual) / na mobília (menos usual)"

Comment: desempoeirar os móveis é: dust the furniture, claro, na língua falada o registro desempoeirar em português é alto. Então, se baixa o registro: tirar o pô dos móveis. Em inglës, não existe diferença de registro da mesma forma que em português.

Answer (score 2):

to wipe down (with a damp cloth) in Portuguese is:

**passar um pano úmido (nos movéis)** or just wipe down: passar um pano (nos movéis)

to dust is **desempoeirar** (formal) or **tirar o pó** (informal)

Limpar is clean and esfregar is scrub. Neither is wipe down.

Comment: Please DO NOT edit my comments. They are clear and fine just the way they are. I do not want a capital letter at /to wipe down/. And I want the words formal and informal to appear just as I wrote them.

Comment: Please put the information of your comment into your profile. People who edit posts will likely find your request there. If someone edits your post anyway, please just rollback the edit and leave a comment for the editor referring to your profile.

Comment: The correct Portuguese verb is "desempoeirar", not "desempoerar".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Yes, that was a typo but not a mistake in meaning. Como dizem os franceses, É preciso se levantar cedo.

Answer (score 1):

"Eu estou **na** sala de estar tirando o pó dos móveis" is current usage.  You can also say "...na sala de estar limpando os móveis", which may be just dusting the furniture or actually cleaning some dirty spots.  "Esfregar" implies using force, usually to scrub out difficult-to-remove stains.  We don't usually "esfregamos" the furniture, but we do "esfregamos o piso ou assoalho" , using electric machines nowadays, wherever there is coninuous traffic of pedestrians.

Comment: Alguém ainda usa enceradeira?

Comment: Curioso o "na" a negrito?! Foi isso mesmo que quiseste?

Comment: Já compreendi :)

Comment: @AndréLyra   Atualmente só vejo aquelas máquinas elétricas, semelhantes às antigas enceradeiras, para limpeza de piso com água e sabão.